# Display or Download Documents Saved in SQL Server with ASP.NET

Tags: html, sql-server, pdf

I have documents saved in a SQL Server database as `varbinary(MAX)`.

I am trying to retrieve the document from the database with below code. The problem I am facing is that no matter the browser I use, I don't get any response back. No dialog the browser just displays the turning circle.
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated..

```
if (e.ButtonID != "Download") 
     return;

int id = 2;
byte[] bytes;
string fileName, contentType;

string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bexsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select Title, WillData, MIMEType from Will_documents where Doc_id = @Id";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
        cmd.Connection = con;

        con.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            sdr.Read();
            bytes = (byte[])sdr["WillData"];
            contentType = sdr["MIMEType"].ToString();
            fileName = sdr["Title"].ToString();

            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = contentType;
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you stepped through the code to ensure that you are really getting a result back from the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually got it Working.

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentType = "application/octetstream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", name));
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", documentBytes.Length.ToString());
Response.BinaryWrite(documentBytes);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```